# How can I resolve this fatal error in Power BI whenerver I try to add a new data source?

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a Power BI project.
I started using a MySQL database that had a small amount of data. I managed myself to create the schema and a very basic dashboard.
After this, I tried to change the data source for a new mysql database with a much bigger amount of data in order to see its performance. The tables are the same. The only thing that changes is the name of the data base and the name of the schema.
The thing is that whenever I try to do this an error always pops up:
Fatal error encountered during data read.

Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException

True

I dont know why this happend. I tried to follow some suggestions I saw in the official forums but they didnt worked for me.
I also deleted the cache but nothing happens ( File-> Options and Settings-> Options-> Data Load -> clear cache)
If you could give me any suggestions, they would be appreciated because I am new to power bi and to be honest I am quite lost with this error.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new data source instead of just editing an existing one?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using mysql with hosted environment? like AWS RDS database ?

Previously I had similar issue getting fatal error when import data via mysql view.
The issue is the processer that used in mysql database was not powerful to run on 100% cpu usage.

So I had to upgrade processer in to powerful and efficient one. And did some changes to query to be efficient.

In your case try to add indexing to the tables and if you are using hosted mysql connection try upgrade processor that can work with 100% usage.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Yes, I am using mysql with a hosted enviroment. I will try and do what you are saying

Comment: @MauricioEstevez Sure, how is your progress ? did you had any chance to resolve tht ?